# How can I get the permissions of a file in octal format?

Tags: bash, file-permissions

... and how can I set them?
Does this work for directories in the same way?
What happens with sticky bit and that more "exotic" stuff?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by [@Gustave](https://superuser.com/users/469158/gustave), the `stat` program (which is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#stat-invocation) and essentially a "Linux" program for that reason, though you may have a *port* or *package* in BSD systems) can do this.  The command

`stat -c "%a %n"`*file*

produces a formatted listing with just the octal mode (including the setuid, setgid and sticky bits encoded) and the filename.  According to the documentation

- `%a` is the "Access rights in octal"
- `%n` is the "File name"

For instance, given this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in $*
do       
    ls -ld "$name"
    stat -c '%a %n' "$name"
done
```

you might see output like this from `myscript /usr/bin /usr/bin/X /usr/bin/bsd-write`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 118784 Jul 11 19:55 /usr/bin
755 /usr/bin
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 9232 Dec 16  2011 /usr/bin/X
6755 /usr/bin/X
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 11000 Jun 17  2010 /usr/bin/bsd-write
2755 /usr/bin/bsd-write
```

You would see 3 or 4 octal digits returned for the *access rights*, depending on whether the setuid, etc., are set.  The leading (fourth) digit combines

- 4 (setuid)
- 2 (setgid)
- 1 (sticky)

The *access rights* returned exclude the extra bits returned by the system call [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) which tell whether the name is a directory (`S_IFDIR`) or file (`S_IFREG`).  All of those bits, by the way, fit into a 16-bit value because of the long-ago Unix implementations in the 1970s and early 1980s—and have [standard values](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html).  Because the *access rights* exclude the file type, you can use that value as-is in the `chmod` command (and also the [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) function), because it is octal, and the [`chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html) command expects that.  Even the setuid, etc., work with octal although things like

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/whatever
```

are more readable.

For further reading

- [What is the first chmod octal digit in a four-digit value for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/what-is-the-first-chmod-octal-digit-in-a-four-digit-value-for)
- [How does the sticky bit work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79395/how-does-the-sticky-bit-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
stat -c "%a %n" <file>
```

seems to work - but I do not know more.

Answer (score 0):

Getting: as Gustave answered.

Setting:

```
chmod 0755 myfile
```

Same for directories. For sticky bit, the first digit should be 1. About the sticky bit: https://askubuntu.com/a/432703